# Recovering password of an Excel spreadsheet file

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-excel, passwords, password-recovery

I have a serious bad situation: I have an Excel file that is password protected and I need to access the information asap for a deadline for a project. Are there any good Excel password recovery tools available for Ubuntu that I could use to achieve this task?

Comment: You are out of luck. All you can do is try to guess the password. If you created the password, try variations with CapsLock on/off, or of mispellings of the passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by using Passware Kit Enterprise could be found [here](http://www.lostpassword.com/kit-enterprise.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Try [Excel Password Remover](http://www.straxx.com/excel/password.html). Note that it will only be able to help you in cases where you can open the document. If you cannot, do that, then this program will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

A few years back I managed to circumvent the password protection on an Office '97 Excel file by doing something stupidly trivial... like exporting the document as a CSV file. This worked because XLS files had been password protected only, not encrypted.